# What is the different between web/static and priv/static in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to elixir and phoenix. Now I have trouble with the static assets in phoenix.

I want to add a js file in my page, and I add the following code in my template:

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/test.js") %>"></script>
```

and then create a js file at `web/static/js/test.js`.

However, I got the error about `test.js` is not found in the browser's console.

I notice there is a `priv/static/js` folder, and I try to create the js file at `priv/static/js/test.js`.

This time, the error gone.

I am really confuse about this.

What is the different between `web/static` and `priv/static` ? If I need to test my static files in develop environment, where should I put the static files?
and how about the production environment ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Priv/static contains processed and concatenated files. I.e they will be saved in this folder after the compilation. However check if your Brunch is working as it takes files from web/static. For better understanding i recommend you go through the doc
 http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets