# Phoenix Framework doesnt work correctly when i save file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a problem with Phoenix.
When I try to save a png file on disk, redirect works incorrectly and I can't load users index page after creating avatar (avatar generator works fine):

```
File.write("web/static/assets/images/avatars/#{input}.png", image)
```

If I delete this line everything is fine.
Any idea why saving files affect routing and how I can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly happens when the redirect "works incorrectly"? What happens when you load the the "users index page" after that? Do you get any error message? Is there any error logged to the console?

Comment: And you probably want to save user generated input to `priv/static/`. `web/static` is usually for assets that should be processed in some way at compile time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151504/what-is-the-different-between-web-static-and-priv-static-in-phoenix.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Iam using identicon generator written in Elixir which creates a png based on users email adress, so in runtime. I could save files in `web/static` folder and then I've got problems with redirect(back to login page without error - status 302) but i cant do it for `priv/static` - just files are not generated without any error msg. I can also generate files in any custom folder in root directory without any errors but how to acces it from templates? Plug.Static doesnt work proper, but maybe i do sth wrong? `plug Plug.Static, at: "/avatars", from: "files/"`

Comment: Try using `File.write!`. `File.write` only returns an error which you're probably ignoring. `write!` will throw the error if one occurs and you'll see it in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoid changing in runtime both folders. Those should be updated when you deploy your app. So instead use custom folder (create config for such) and then create a handler which should stream file to browser or use nginx/apache and map that folder as static content folder so your app is not bothering with streaming potentially large files. Don't use Static Assets module since it knows only for web and priv folder. Instead create yours which should resolve relative/absolute paths.

Comment: That works. I've created separate folder and with correct configuration, without touching statics everything's ok. Thanks for help!